# install,opencv 4,5,1 error: libtiff.so.5: undefined reference to `jbg_enc_out'

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, computer-vision

### platform:
Ubuntu 18.04,install opencv 4.5.1  and  opencv-contrib,meet  with error:

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libjbig.so.0, needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libthai.so.0, needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5: undefined reference to `jbg_enc_out'

//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5: undefined reference to `jbg_dec_getsize'

//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `th_uni2tis@LIBTHAI_0.1'

---

Comment: Are you building OpenCV from source? If yes, you may need to set some variables to make sure that TIFF library is built.

Comment: yes ,building  from source, I think TIFF already built,but can't find  libjbig.so.0

Comment: I think for TIFF there must be some settings to enable/disable building of that library. Can you check that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12342735

Comment: BTW, if you don't need TIFF, you can simply disable it in the configuration.

Comment: ohhhhhhh,thanks you very  much!!!!!!!!!!! I  install libjbig,and then this  problem solved,thanks